# Attributes of tables in VS by coding with C#

Tags: sql, key

I have this table:

[image]

Please, don't mind because it's on my native language and it doesn't matter..

Those are all attributes in table but when I go to Visual StudioS and try to use some of this I get this one:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I see all "normal" attributes in VS but where is those FK attributes?
I need them to compare few ones and get values?

I can't use it from name of other tables [dot] attribute etc...
like for example:

I need this:   `table1.ID == table2.ID`
and not this:  `table1.ID == table1.table2.ID`

Where or what is FK attribute in VS that is shown in SQL table ??

```
public void setParametri(int desID)
    {

        foreach (desavanje d in DM_Class.dc.desavanje)
           if (d.desavanjeID == desID)
            {


                //THIS FIRST 4 LINES WORKS PERFECTLY
                this.naziv_des = d.naziv_des;
                this.datum_po = d.datum_pocetka.ToString();
                this.datum_zav = d.datum_kraja.ToString();
                this.cijena = d.cijena_des;

                //foreach (klijenti k in DM_Class.dc.klijenti)
                //{
                //    if(k.klijentID == //WHAT TO PUT HERE TO COMPARE VALUE klijentID from tables klijenti with FK value in table desavanje)
                //        this.klijent = k.Ime + ' ' + k.Prezime;
                //}



               //ON THIS LINE I'M GETTING ERROR - Object reference not set to an instance of an object. but why? 
               //I have data on that field in DB ? 
                 //this.grad = d.mjesto_desavanja.gradovi.naziv_grada.ToString();              
                //this.mjesto = d.mjesto_desavanja.naziv_objekta;
                //this.organizator = d.organizator.Ime + ' ' + d.organizator.Prezime;
                //this.tip = d.tip_desavanja.vrsta_des;
                this.klijent = d.klijenti.Ime + ' ' + d.klijenti.Prezime;
                //this.status = d.status_desavanja.naziv_statusa;
                //this.br_gost = d.specifikacija_desavanja.br_osoba;


            }
        }
```

If is there other solution to get values for attributes I'm willing to try it without using another foreach loop?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could indicate this information in the question itself instead of linking (with not even real links) images.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for here.  The code itself doesn't have a concept of "foreign keys".  C# is object-oriented, not relational.  What technology are you using here?  If you're just using Linq to Sql, for example, then the generated data context classes should be foreign-key aware and should have class properties where you can access related classes.  Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish and how you're not able to accomplish it?

Comment: Stackoverflow rules for new users doesn't allow posting real links so I put it like that.. It's easier to see that to read and try to understand and imagine.. But I'll put it with words too..            Ok, I'm using ADO.NET to work with DB and in this case I must take data from few tables but in foreach loop I can't join tables to gather information. So I tried to use another foreach to loop other table in DB to extract data from it. To do that I need to compare ID's that are FK in first one and PK in second one. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @GabrijelGaleBaban: It would be a lot clearer if you put the code in your question.  When you say you're using ADO.NET, show the actual classes/objects you're using.  DataSets/DataTables?  Some strongly-typed objects?  The question as it stands right now doesn't really make a lot of sense (at least to me).  Show the code you're using to get the information you're trying to get and indicate in that code where the problem is.  The very concept of "joining" in your C# objects implies to me that you're trying to get help on an already incorrect approach, so we may need to step back a bit.

Comment: @GabrijelGaleBaban: Your variable and type names don't give _any_ indication of what they mean (and don't follow C# conventions), so it's very difficult to follow.  For the null reference exception, you'll have to determine which object on that line of code is `null`.  You're reaching 4 levels deep (which significantly breaks the Law Of Demeter), and one of those levels is apparently `null` on its parent object.  The inner loop doesn't really make sense because it's only retaining the value of the last record.  So why loop?  Why not just use the last matching record?

Comment: @GabrijelGaleBaban: This looks a lot more like Entity Framework or Linq To Sql than plain old ADO.NET.  (It definitely _isn't_ plain old ADO.NET.)  If the `desavanje` table has a FK to the `klijenti` table then the generated code for the `desavanje` object should have a property linking it to related records in the `klijenti` object collection.  You _should_ be able to use something like `d.klijentis.Last()` or `d.klijentiReference.Last()` depending on how it's constructing the fields for you.  Does the `klijentiReference` property contain the records you're looking for?

Comment: I don't have .Last() option.. What represent FK attribute in some table?

Comment: Ok, i managed this.. I've used linq querry's to generate data that I need and in that querrys I've compared needed ID's and finally get some working stuff..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed this.. I've used a linq query to generate data that I need and in that queries I've compared needed ID's and finally get some working stuff.